# Search for specific id in REST API

Tags: php, api

I'm trying to create search in RESTful API to search for specific id and this is the code that I write:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

include_once 'dbconfig.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$channel = new Channel($db);

$keywords=isset($_GET["id"]) ? $_GET["id"] : "";

$stmt = $channel->searchChannel($keywords);
$num = $stmt->rowCount();

if($num>0){

    $channel_arr["channel"]=array();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        extract($row);

        $cat = $row['cat'];

        $channel_item = array(
            "id" => $id,
            "title" => $title,
            "cat" => $cat,
        );

      $stmt2 = $channel->searchChannels($cat);

        array_push($channel_arr["channel"], $channel_item);
    }


    http_response_code(200);

    echo json_encode($channel_arr);
}

else{
    http_response_code(404);

    echo json_encode(
        array("message" => "No channels found.")
    );
}

class Channel{

    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "esite_channels";

    public $id;
    public $title;
    public $cat;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

function searchChannel($keywords){

    $query = "SELECT
                e.id, e.title, e.image, e.streamname, e.enable, e.cat, e.app
            FROM
                " . $this->table_name . " e
            WHERE
                e.id LIKE ? 
                ";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    $keywords=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($keywords));
    $keywords = "%{$keywords}%";

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $keywords);

    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
}

}


?>
```

it works fine while I search for id 20 with this link:
http://127.0.0.1/api/search.php?id=20

it bring data of that id like this:

```
   [
    {
    channel: [
    {
    id: "20",
    title: "title",
    cat: "Sports",
    }
    ]
    }
]
```

but when change the id for 22 for example:
http://127.0.0.1/api/search.php?id=22

it bring me all items that contain 22 in the id like this:

```
[
{
channel: [
{
id: "22",
title: "BEIN SPORTS 3HD",
cat: "Sports",
},
{
id: "122",
title: "Fine Living HD",
cat: "Entertainment",
}
]
}
]
```

it bring 22 and 122 id while I want only the 22 and when I search for 122 I want it to bring me 122 only
how do this

Comment: try this `WHERE e.id = ?`

Comment: why would you use LIKE when you donot want other related results. Try %{$keywords} or {$keywords}% or =. which best suits you.

Comment: when you want to retreive that only the ID **22**, you must change your query in WHERE e.id LIKE ?  to WHERE e.id = ?

Comment: I was writing the answer while you were commenting guys :) All are correct yes.

Comment: you are very slow in writing keep practicing ;-)

Comment: guys I already tried e.id = ? but it bring me the same result

Comment: and use like this `$keywords = "{$keywords}";`

Comment: @BhargavChudasama yes I was writing slowly because of the formatting :)

Comment: @TahaPaksu what you format after read comment

Comment: thanks guys it works after I change this $keywords = "%{$keywords}%";
 to this $keywords = "{$keywords}";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `e.id LIKE ?` to `e.id = ?` in your query. And remove this line:

```
$keywords = "%{$keywords}%";
```

Because when you use `LIKE` with `"%keyword%"` structure, `LIKE` operator searches for the records **containing** that value. You can also use the `LIKE` operator without the wildcards (`e.id LIKE '22'`), you can also achieve what you want. But the direct search is better.

```
$query = "SELECT
            e.id, e.title, e.image, e.streamname, e.enable, e.cat, e.app
        FROM
            " . $this->table_name . " e
        WHERE
            e.id = ? 
            ";

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

$keywords=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($keywords));
$stmt->bindParam(1, $keywords);
```

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks it works after I change this $keywords = "%{$keywords}%";
 to this $keywords = "{$keywords}";

Comment: That's like `$keywords = $keywords`. No need for that.